# Equimeasurable functions of $p(\cdot) :[0;1] \to [1;\infty)$ and $p(\cdot\cdot) : [0;1]^2 \to [1; \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $p(\cdot) :[0;1] \to [1;\infty)$ be a measurable function.

Define $p^{*}(x)$ as the decreasing rearrangement of the measurable function $p(\cdot)$.

Hence we  know that $p(\cdot)$ and $ p^{*}(x)$ are equimeasurable to each other. ( Since $p(\cdot)$ is positive-valued).

Let  $p(\cdot\cdot) : [0;1]^2 \to [1; \infty)$ be a measurable function.

Define $p^{*}(x,y)$ as the decreasing rearrangement of the measurable function $p(\cdot\cdot)$.

Thereby we know that $p(\cdot\cdot)$ and $p^{*}(x,y)$ are equimeasurable to each other.(Since $p(\cdot\cdot)$ is positive-valued).

Define $\bar p(x,y) = p^{*}(x) + p^{*}(y)$ .

There is the question:

Will $\bar p(x,y)$ be equimeasurable to $p(\cdot\cdot)$ ?

I'm trying to figure out something from these definitions:

[image]

[image]

Note that :

$(1)$ Nonnegative functions $f$ and $g$ are called equimeasurable if $\eta_f = \eta_g$ , i.e.,

$$m\{f \gt y \} = m\{g \gt y \} .$$

$(2)$ Functions $|f|$ and $f^{*}$ are equimeasurable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you let $p^{*}(x)$ and $p^{*}(y)$ when $p$ is a two-variable function? Did you mean something akin to $(p(x, \cdot))^*(y) + (p(\cdot, y))^*(x)$ perhaps?

Comment: @BrunoB I don't understand your question properly. The decreasing rearrangement of the $p(x,y)$ $ = p^{*}(x,y) $ . $\bar p(x,y)$is different function from $p(x,y) $ It's represented as the sum of the rearrangement functions of $p(x)$ and $p(y)$.

Comment: @BrunoB I understand now. Yes I've meant something like that. I edited the question.

Comment: Take $p(x,y)=\frac{1}{p^*(x)+p^*(y)+1}$.  can somebody check is that a counter example,  seriously speaking i don't know.

Comment: @HappieHappieHappie why do you think that it’s a counterexample?

Comment: $\frac{1}{y+1}$ vs $y$

Comment: i am not sure i understand the definition properly,  That's why i asked someone to check,  if i understand it or not.

Comment: How would MSE be able to answer a question which even the great John Nash can't ? :P

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom John nash wasn’t an expert of mathematical analysis

Comment: That's a good point